# Using a merged array in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image

Not sure exactly how to word this but hopefully you'll get my drift. I'm trying to use my If statement to merger the contents of my images array into another array, there is then a function that uses that array to do a picture slide show.

I feel that I should mention that this is a school assignment, so I'd like to not change the `chgSlide` function if I don't have too.

I think my problem is that when i have `var myPix=[]` it clears the merger. But i'm not sure really what the solution is, i've tried just doing `myPix=redCarsPic` but it didn't work.

Also, within the code i commented out that ways i had merged the array, i'm not sure if a certain approach is better than an other, i'm sort of partial to the jquery and would like to be able to keep that approach if i can.

Heres my script block:

```
function radioCheck(){
if (document.getElementById("redCars").checked){
    //alert("red"); Array.prototype.push.apply(myPix,redCarsPic);
    //alert("red"); myPix.push.apply(myPix, redCarsPic);
    $.merge(myPix,redCarsPic)
    alert(redCarsPic+"  r2");

};
if (document.getElementById("blueCars").checked){
    alert("blue"); myPix.push.apply(myPix, blueCarsPic);
};
if (document.getElementById("greenCars").checked){
    alert("green"); myPix.push.apply(myPix, greenCarsPic);
};
}

var myPix=[];
thisPic=0;
imgCt=myPix.length-1;

alert(myPix+"mpixalt")


function chgSlide(direction){
if(document.images){
    thisPic=thisPic+direction
        if(thisPic>imgCt){
            thisPic=0
        }
        if(thisPic<0){
            thisPic-imgct
        }
document.myPicture.src=myPix[thisPic]

}
}

var redCarsPic =["images/redCarsA.jpg","images/redCarsB.jpg","images/redCarsC.jpg","images/redCarsD.jpg","images/redCarsE.jpg"];
var blueCarsPic =["images/blueCarsA.jpg","images/blueCarsB.jpg","images/blueCarsC.jpg","images/blueCarsD.jpg","images/blueCarsE.jpg"];
var greenCarsPic =["images/greenCarsA.jpg","images/greenCarsB.jpg","images/greenCarsC.jpg","images/greenCarsD.jpg","images/greenCarsE.jpg"];
```

Heres the entire code if needed:
http://pastebin.com/YLtWFciE

Comment: What is `redCarsPic`?  Is it an array?  Or a single image?

Comment: @jfriend00: It is defined globally; scroll down. :)

Comment: You can use either `.splice()` or `.push()` to add another array of images onto an existing array.

Comment: @jfriend00 it is an array of images

Comment: What was wrong with `Array.prototype.push.apply(myPix,redCarsPic);`?  Or, you could have just used `myPix.push.apply(myPix, redCarsPic);`.

Comment: OP, I don't understand what your question is. You are telling us what you are doing, but not what the problem is. `$.merge` should, indeed, merge the second array into the first one (as should the commented out code mentioned by @jfriend00). What is going wrong?

Comment: @jfriend00 I did, it's commented out in the first If

Comment: So, what's the question then?

Comment: The problem is that the second function that uses myPix doesnt work, and the alert i put in to check to see what was in myPix comes back empty

Comment: One problem is that you're not updating `imgCt` when you change the array.  You should probalby just not use that variable at all.  Just refer to `myPix.length` whenever you want the count.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay, but what does that have to do with the myPix array being empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press the submit button in your form, it tries to submit your form which causes the page to be reloaded, thus reinitializing all your state back to a new page which is an empty array.

You can stop the form from submitting either by changing the button to be just a normal button, not a submit button or by block the default action of the form submission.

The simplest change is to just change this:

```
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Go!" onclick="radioCheck()"/>
```

to this:

```
<input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Go!" onclick="radioCheck()"/>
```

With no submit button, the form will not be submitted and the page will not reload.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4bx35hjy/

---

FYI, it is also possible to cancel the form submission in your `radioCheck()` function before it occurs, but since you never want to submit the form, it seems better to just not ever have a submit button in the first place.

Comment: @gchian - the second alert is from when your page reloads and thus it again has an empty array.  Remember, Javascript state is not preserved form one page load to the next.  It starts over again each time the page is loaded.  Your form submit was reloading the page right after it ran `radioCheck()`.